# Почему остается пуст массив $_FILES

Tags: html5, изображения, php7

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="file" name="name">
<input type="submit">
</form>
<?php if (isset($_POST['name'])){
 echo "<pre>".var_dump($_FILES)."</pre>";
}?>
</body>
</html>
```

Объясните пожалуйста, почему я получаю пустой массив $_FILES когда загружаю какое-нибудь изображение

Answer (score 0):

в form вставь enctype="multipart/form-datа"

Comment: Это правильный ответ, но было бы неплохо объяснить детали новичку.